# Why are my catboost predictions pushed towards 0 and 1 and how to smooth it?

Tags: r, distributions, predictive-models, catboost

I am using catboost in a classification problem with extreme unbalanced classes (positive class consists of ~ 0.25% of all observations).
I fitted a model using catboost in R and got a very good result, both on the train and on a unseen test set (AUC ~ 0.97). In theory, I do not have any data leakage.

When I check the distribution of the probabilities, I can see that they are pushed towards 0 and  1, see picture:

[image]

I guess that is per se not bad, since the model seems to be able to split negative and positive cases. However, **I wonder if this distribution is normal and if there is a way to avoid the algorithm "pushing" the scores so extremely towards 0 and 1.**

I cannot really offer a reproducible example since this belongs to a work project I am working on. If it helps, this is the parameter set I worked with (after doing some random search with CV):

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "Normal" as in typical?  I suppose it depends on the model and data.  One way to prevent this is to add regularization, but then your AUC will be hurt.  This distribution of probabilities is not necessarily bad, its only bad it the probabilities are not calibrated (assuming you care for that sort of thing anyway).

Comment: The concentration of predicted probabilities near 0 and 1 is very standard behavior ("normal") for gradient-boosted tree models. Reducing the number of leaves (depth), reducing the number of boosting rounds, increasing the learning rate, increasing the penalization on the boosting weights are options that might ameliorate this behavior, but it's not obvious form the question description that this distribution of probabilities is a **problem**. You're measuring AUC, which implies you want to partition the classes.

Comment: One possible problem with boosting is a lack of calibration, otherwise, as you say getting most examples right is nice.

Comment: Yes, "normal" as typical I meant @DemetriPananos. Do you maybe know ways to add regularization and/or calibration to a catboost model in R? Some time ago I was playing with some methods but they were not very successful... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi @Sycorax, thanks for your answer. The distribution of probabilities is a problem for me because I would like to (or I have to) split the scores into deciles. With this distribution, the first 9 deciles mostly contain scores between 0 and 0.1, while the last decile contains the scores between 0.1 and 1. That is why I would like to "smooth" the distribution a bit. 
Thanks for the advice, I will play around with the parameters a bit.

Comment: Ok but why is that a problem? What problem does dividing the the predictions into “smooth” deciles solve?